# When is a WooCommerce session started?

Tags: woocommerce

I read in https://mikejolley.com/2013/12/20/problems-with-cart-sessions-and-woocommerce/

"On page load, a session ID is created for a user."

But what page are we talking about. When people come to my site they first hit a home page.  From there they can select "Pricing" to go to a "Pricing" page.  And from there they can select from a list of items and go to a checkout page, where the item they selected on the Pricing page is seen in the cart.

But at what point is a WooCommerce session created (I know this is not the PHP $_SESSION).

What I'm really after is the soonest I can empty cart,since I keep seeing items from the last visit in the cart, in addition to what was selected this time,  when I get to the checkout page.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't common sense say that the earliest point you can empty the cart is immediately after checkout?

Comment: Not at all.  The earliest would be before anything is added to the cart, to make sure nothing is left from the last session.

Comment: If you clear it immediately after checkout, there can't be anything left from the last session. If the previous session never got to checkout, then the user may have wanted to leave them there. I sometimes put things in my cart at Amazon that I don't want right this second, but I want to remember next time I order other things.

Comment: You're right.  I shouldn't be trying to clear these previous items.  They're supposed to stay there, until you either buy them or you explicitly remove them from your cart.